# How does the Docx rendering in Pages compare to Mac Office 2011

Tags: pages, iwork, ms-office

It's about time for me to bit the bullet and buy either iWork 09 or MS Office 2011.  My main concern is rendering docx files (I've been using OpenOffice for many years, but the .doc and .docx rendering is still suspect).

How do they compare?

Does Pages render a docx file at least 95% accurate?

From the info online I understand that Pages cannot save in docx format.

Which do you prefer?

**To clarify**
I'm talking about more complex layouts.

Comment: Will the docx files you receive have text, images, and basic formatting? Or tables, complex embedded objects, etc?

Comment: Another option is to use Google Docs.You can try out a somewhat stripped down version without a Google account http://docs.google.com/demo. This is really all I use, but you should see if it fits your needs. One thing the new version of Google Docs boasts is better importing capabilities over the old version: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=176442&hl=en. (If you already have Google Docs you can upgrade to the new version in the settings I think... that's how I did it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question.

I've found that Pages does a much better job at rendering more complex DOCX layouts than OpenOffice currently. Pages does not save in DOCX format.

BTW.... You can get pages for $20 through the new Apple App Store :)